# How to mock data from service as hook with React Testing Library?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm starting using *React Testing Library* to make tests for a React Application, but i'm struggling to mock the data in a component that makes API calls using a **Hook** as service.

My component is just a functional component, with nothing extraordinary:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import Skeleton from '@material-ui/lab/Skeleton'

import usePanelClient from '../../../clients/PanelClient/usePanelClient'
import useUtils from '../../../hooks/useUtils'
import IconFile from '../../../assets/img/panel/ico-file.svg'
import IconExclamation from '../../../assets/img/panel/ico-exclamation.svg'
import IconPause from '../../../assets/img/panel/awesome-pause-circle.svg'
import './PendingAwards.scss'

const PendingAwards = () => {
  const pendingAwardsRef = useRef(null)
  const location = useLocation()

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)
  const [pendingAwards, setPendingAwards] = useState({})
  const panelClient = usePanelClient()
  const { formatCurrency } = useUtils()

  useEffect(() => {
    panelClient()
      .getPendingAwards()
      .then((response) => {
        setLoading(false)
        setPendingAwards(response.data)
      })
  }, [panelClient])

  useEffect(() => {
    const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(location.search)
    if (searchParams.get('scrollTo') === 'pendingAwards') {
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: 'smooth',
      })
    }
  }, [location])

  return (
    <div
      id="pendingAwards"
      className="pending-awards-container"
      ref={pendingAwardsRef}
    >
      <span className="pending-awards-container__title">Prêmios Pendentes</span>
      {loading && (
        <div className="skeleton-box">
          <Skeleton width="100%" height="70px" />
          <Skeleton width="100%" height="70px" />
        </div>
      )}

      {!loading && (
        <div className="pending-awards-values">
          <div className="pending-awards-container__quantity">
            <div className="pending-awards-container__quantity-container">
              <span className="pending-awards-container__quantity-container-title">
                Quantidade
              </span>
              <span className="pending-awards-container__quantity-container-content">
                <div className="pending-awards-container__quantity-container-content__icon-box">
                  <img src={IconFile} alt="Ícone de arquivo" />
                </div>
                {pendingAwards.quantity ? pendingAwards.quantity : '0'}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div className="pending-awards-container__amount">
            <div className="pending-awards-container__amount-container">
              <span className="pending-awards-container__amount-container-title">
                Valor Pendente
              </span>
              <span className="pending-awards-container__amount-container-content">
                <div className="pending-awards-container__amount-container-content__icon-box">
                  <img src={IconPause} alt="Ícone Pause" />
                </div>
                {pendingAwards.amount
                  ? formatCurrency(pendingAwards.amount)
                  : 'R$ 0,00'}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="pending-awards-container__commission">
            <div className="pending-awards-container__commission-container">
              <span className="pending-awards-container__commission-container-title">
                Comissão Pendente
              </span>
              <span className="pending-awards-container__commission-container-content">
                <div className="pending-awards-container__commission-container-content__icon-box">
                  <img src={IconExclamation} alt="Ícone exclamação" />
                </div>
                {pendingAwards.commission
                  ? formatCurrency(pendingAwards.commission)
                  : 'R$ 0,00'}
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}
export default PendingAwards
```

My service that makes the API calls it is written like this:

```
import { useCallback } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const usePanelClient = () => {
  const getQuotationCard = useCallback(() => axios.get('/api/cards/quotation'), [])
  const getCommissionCard = useCallback(() => axios.get('/api/cards/commission'), [])
  const getPendingAwards = useCallback(() => axios.get('/api/premium/pending'), [])

  return useCallback(() => ({
    getQuotationCard,
    getCommissionCard,
    getPendingAwards,
  }), [
    getQuotationCard,
    getCommissionCard,
    getPendingAwards,
  ])
}

export default usePanelClient
```

In my current test I've tried mocking the hook like this, but I **did not** have success:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom'
import { createMemoryHistory } from 'history'

import PendingAwards from './PendingAwards'

describe('PendingAwards Component', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.mock('../../../clients/PanelClient/usePanelClient', () => {
      const mockData = {
        quantity: 820,
        amount: 26681086.12,
        commission: 5528957.841628,
      }
      return {
        getPendingAwards: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(mockData)),
      }
    })
  })

  it('should render the PendingAwards', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory()
    history.push = jest.fn()
    const { container } = render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <PendingAwards />
      </Router>,
    )
    expect(container).toBeInTheDocument()
  })

  it('should render the PendingAwards', () => {
    const history = createMemoryHistory()
    history.push({
      search: '&scrollTo=pendingAwards',
    })
    window.scrollTo = jest.fn()
    render(
      <Router history={history}>
        <PendingAwards />
      </Router>,
    )
    expect(window.scrollTo).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ behavior: 'smooth', top: 0 })
  })
})
```

May someone help me resolving this? I don't feel like this is something hard, but I've tried several things, and nothing seems to resolve it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should move jest.mock outside beforeEach block. The other problem I see is that mock data should has a property called data because it is what you are expecting in your component (response.data)

Comment: @lissettdm I'll try changing to that, ty

Comment: I've tried doing like this, but It seems like it didn't work:

`jest.mock('../../../clients/PanelClient/usePanelClient', () => {
    const mockData = {
      quantity: 820,
      amount: 26681086.12,
      commission: 5528957.841628,
    }
    return {
      getPendingAwards: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({ data: mockData })),
    }
  })
`
I'm also getting this error:
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Network Error

Answer (score 1):

You must call `jest.mock` at the top level of the module and for mocking ES6 modules with a default export you should use `__esModule: true`

```
jest.mock('../../../clients/PanelClient/usePanelClient', () => {
  const mockData = {
    quantity: 820,
    amount: 26681086.12,
    commission: 5528957.841628,
  }
  return {
    __esModule: true,
    default: ()=> ({
      getPendingAwards: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({data: mockData})),
    }),
}});
```

Comment: I'm getting this warning, and it seems that the result from the mock wasn't returned in the component:

(node:91604) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Network Error

Comment: if you are getting a network error is because the mock is not working and axios functions have been called. In jest docs there is a warning: Importing a module in a setup file (as specified by setupFilesAfterEnv) will prevent mocking for the module in question, as well as all the modules that it imports. See https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options

Comment: My setup file only has this:

import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'

Comment: Are you sure this path '../../../clients/PanelClient/usePanelClient' is OK in according to your test file?

Comment: I think so, because i'm using this hook on my component aswell.
I have to put the jest.mock... inside the describe right?

Comment: You should put it outside the describe. If you want to use it inside describe, then you should use jest.doMock

Comment: Tried doing it outside, but now I get  TypeError: panelClient is not a function, doing with jest.doMock inside the describe, I don't get errors, but still, the response is not returned, so it is not working aswell :(

Comment: About TypeError: panelClient, try to add a console.log before calling panelClient() in useEffect and check if it is getting the module mock

Comment: no success with that path, could do it with another solution